# search for any string value in an ordered dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, collections, ordereddictionary

I have a nested ordered dictionary i.e. a ordered dictionary, some of whose values are ordered dictionary that contain further ordered dictionaries.
When I use the collections module and use the following call

```
yOrDict = yaml_ordered_dict.load('ApplyForm.yml')
```

then I get an ordered dictionary `yOrDict` from the yml file `ApplyForm.yml`.

Say that yOrDict has just one key (`ApplyForm`) and a value which in turn is an ordered dictionary.

Further call gives another ordered dictionary:

```
yOrDictLevel1 = yOrDict.get('ApplyForm')
```

say that `yOrDictLevel1` has six keys whose values contain ordered dictionaries.

say that at some place one of the ordered dictionary has a value named as `Block`.

Is there a call/function/method in python by which I can check if Block appears in the top level ordered dictionary - `yOrDict` ?
    i.e. I want to check if the string "Block" is at all there in yOrDict ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
def find_value(needle, container):
    # Already found the object. Return.
    if needle == container:
        return True

    values = None
    if isinstance(container, dict):
        values = container.values()
    elif hasattr(container, '__iter__'):
        values = container.__iter__()

    if values is None:
        return False

    # Check deeper in the container, if needed.
    for val in values:
        if find_value(needle, val):
            return True

    # No match found.
    return False
```

Usage:

```
In [3]: d = { 'test': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'd1': { 'd2': 'Block', 'a': 'b'} }

In [4]: find_value('Block', d)
Out[4]: True
```

Edit: testing whether a value contains `needle`:

```
def find_value(needle, container):
    # Already found the object. Return.
    if isinstance(container, basestring) and needle in container:
        return True

    values = None
    if isinstance(container, dict):
        values = container.values()
    elif hasattr(container, '__iter__'):
        values = container.__iter__()

    if values is None:
        return False

    # Check deeper in the container, if needed.
    for val in values:
        if find_value(needle, val):
            return True

    # No match found.
    return False
```

Comment: `result = find_value('Block',yOrDictLevel1)  
      if (result == True)  
          print ('Block found')  
      else  
      print ('Block not found')`  shows syntax error

Comment: tried indenting in following ways : 1. put code in back ticks ` code ` 2. put two spaces after each code line to give line breaks. didnt succeed in indenting

Comment: my yOrDict looks like this : `OrderedDict([('ApplyForm', OrderedDict([('$type', 'Block'), ('TITLE', OrderedDict([('$io', 'output'), ('$type', 'text'), ('$value', 'Beijing 3DS Application Form')]))]))])`  How can I seach for Beijing in this ordered dictionary ?

Comment: `    result = find_value('Beijing',yOrDict)  
      print('result',result)`  gave the output as ('result', False)

Comment: Your question referred to value _equality_, not _containment_. I'll update my answer to reflect your second case in a second. Edit: updated my answer.

Comment: Voilà, it works ! thanks. yes my original questions did not explicitly mention that i am referring to containment and not just equality. but i still can't figure out how to put line breaks in a piece of code in stackoverflow commenting :-(

Comment: Youre welcome! For future reference, if you need to change the test (equality, or something more sophisticated), all you need to do is change the condition after `# Already found the object. Return.`. This is where all the value comparison is done. And i agree that it is not possible to insert new lines into comments because that could kind of disrupt the flow of the website

Comment: great ! another question. i tried checking of containment of the key $type and it failed. any way to check for the keys $type or $io or others starting with $ ?

Comment: It is because `$type` and `$io` are __keys__ not __values__ in your dicts. You would have to change the logic to check for keys instead of values.

Answer (score 0):

```
if "Block" in yOrDict.get('ApplyForm').values():
    print "Found Block value"
```

It isn't explicitly a method of the higher level meta-dictionary, since it does a get and searches through the values, but its concise and does the trick.

**edit** response to your comment

```
if (("Beijing" in val) for key,val in yOrDict.get('ApplyForm')iteritems()):
    print "Found Beijing"
```

Comment: my yOrDict looks like this : OrderedDict([('ApplyForm', OrderedDict([('$type', 'Block'), ('TITLE', OrderedDict([('$io', 'output'), ('$type', 'text'), ('$value', 'Beijing 3DS Application Form')]))]))]) How can I seach for Beijing in this ordered dictionary ?

Comment: ` if "Beijing" in yOrDict.get('ApplyForm').values():
    print "Found Beijing value"
  else:
    print "did not find Beijing value in yOrDict"`  gave the output did not find Beijing value in yOrDict

Comment: @tauseef_india that is correct because Beijing is not located where That code is looking, I can change the code to look in that higher level dictionary

Comment: @tauseef_india  Also that dictionary looks *terribly* formatted

Comment: `OrderedDict([('ApplyForm', OrderedDict([('$type', 'Block'), ('TITLE', OrderedDict([('$io', 'output'), ('$type', 'text'), ('$value', 'Beijing 3DS Application Form')]))]))]) `

Comment: i am looking for containment of Beijing anywhere in the ordered dictionary. But your previous code worked for locating Block whereas it did failed to locate Beijing when Block was not a value for the ordered dictionary. wonder why ?

Comment: It worked to find block because it was looking in the sub-dictionary.  Would you like to also look for Beijing in the subdictionary?  If so, see my updated code @tauseef_india

Comment: @tauseef_india I'm sorry, I'll let you know when it is workign